# Python Requests fails on a specific HTTPS site, although its certificate is valid

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, certificate

We're using a Python package that internally uses `requests` to access an online service. The service is located at https://dsbox02.isi.edu:8888/  . If you follow the link with your browser, you'll see that the page opens up, and that it has a valid certificate.

The following Python code, however, fails:

```
import requests
requests.get('https://dsbox02.isi.edu:8888')
```

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dsbox02.isi.edu', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)')))

This happens on Windows 10 and Python 3.7, Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.6 and the `python:latest` docker image, with Python 3.9. On a Mac with Python 3.8 it does work.

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://dsbox02.isi.edu:8888/ check this out.

Comment: Brilliant! This should be posted as an answer!

Comment: Posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ssl certificates that are not trusted in all web browsers. You may need to install an Intermediate/chain certificate to link it to a trusted root certificate.

The easiest way is to check your website with a ssl checker. Such as: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://dsbox02.isi.edu:8888/